# external .js only runs some parts of code

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to learn Javascript, and am having trouble with an external .js file.  I am trying to make a div that changes colors when different radio buttons are selected.  I have gotten it to work using "onclick" property and a js function.  I cannot get the div to default to a color using javascript, though.  Here is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspract_j.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="jspract.html" method="post">
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:divcol(this.value);" name="color" id="red" value="red">Red</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:divcol(this.value);" name="color" id="yellow" value="yellow">Yellow</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:divcol(this.value);" name="color" id="blue" value="blue">Blue</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:divcol(this.value);" name="color" id="orange" value="orange">Orange</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:divcol(this.value);" name="color" id="purple" value="purple">Purple</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:divcol(this.value);" name="color" id="green" value="green">Green</label><br>
        <br>
    </form>
    <div id="change"></div>
    </body>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function divcol(color)
{
    document.getElementById("change").style.backgroundColor=color;
}

document.getElementById("change").style.backgroundColor="pink";
```

The radio buttons change the color, working as intended.  The div appears white upon load, however, not pink.  What is going wrong here?

I feel like I am missing some key part of how Javascript works.  I've tried scouring the internet, but all I find are posts about people incorrectly linking the .js file.  Mine is linked properly, but not executing how I would like it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the color before the `dom` is getting loaded. Below is the code which works perfectly. **Place your script before the closing of body tag**

http://jsbin.com/UkUGeJu/1/

On the load the color is **pink** and when you change the **corresponding color** gets updated.